How to recycle shorter vectors in map2() without using rep()?
I’m trying to run the following code:
xx <- 1:12
yy <- 1:3
map2(xx, yy, ~ .x / .y)

However, I encountered an error. I assumed that map2() would automatically recycle the shorter vector (i.e., extend the length of yy to match xx), but it seems that's not the case.
My desired output :
1
1
1
4
2.5
2
7
4
3
10
5.5
4

Is there a way to make map2() handle vector recycling automatically without manually using rep()?

You could use mapply() from base R (instead of purrr::map2()):
mapply(\(.x, .y) .x / .y, xx, yy)
# or 
mapply(`/`, xx, yy)

#  [1]  1.0  1.0  1.0  4.0  2.5  2.0  7.0  4.0  3.0
# [10] 10.0  5.5  4.0


We can use Map():
unlist(Map(`/`, xx, yy))

#>  [1]  1.0  1.0  1.0  4.0  2.5  2.0  7.0  4.0  3.0 10.0  5.5  4.0

If you really need to use map2(), then we can do something like this:
data.frame(xx, yy) %>% {map2(.$xx, .$yy, `/`)} %>% unlist()

#>  [1]  1.0  1.0  1.0  4.0  2.5  2.0  7.0  4.0  3.0 10.0  5.5  4.0


You are right regarding the function being complicated. They should take this approach

I am not sure why you need the map2 function yet / is vectorized:
just do:
xx/yy
 [1]  1.0  1.0  1.0  4.0  2.5  2.0  7.0  4.0  3.0 10.0  5.5  4.0

If the function is not vectorized, vectorize it using Vectorize which will recycle the arguments

I suspect they have a more complicated function than  / . Although, this is a good point considering their mre.

If you want to use the "recycle" feature, you can construct a data.frame and then call map2 via do.call or exec, for example
> do.call(map2, c(unname(data.frame(xx, yy)), `/`))
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 1

[[3]]
[1] 1

[[4]]
[1] 4

[[5]]
[1] 2.5

[[6]]
[1] 2

[[7]]
[1] 7

[[8]]
[1] 4

[[9]]
[1] 3

[[10]]
[1] 10

[[11]]
[1] 5.5

[[12]]
[1] 4

or
> exec(map2, !!!c(data.frame(.x = xx, .y = yy), `/`))
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 1

[[3]]
[1] 1

[[4]]
[1] 4

[[5]]
[1] 2.5

[[6]]
[1] 2

[[7]]
[1] 7

[[8]]
[1] 4

[[9]]
[1] 3

[[10]]
[1] 10

[[11]]
[1] 5.5

[[12]]
[1] 4

